# Date format convertion in R

Tags: r, string, date

I have a problem with transforming to date format a variable.
I have the following column:

```
fechas
20200509
20200601
20200505
20200610
20200612
20200529
```

where, for the first line 2020 is the year, 05 is the month and 09 is the day. So I need to convert this column into:

```
fechas
2020-05-09
2020-06-01
2020-05-05
2020-06-10
2020-06-12
2020-05-29
```

I have thought of a solution of separating the characters and paste them with `-`, but I wanted to know if there is a more straight way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the builtin `strptime`

```
# Data
dates <- c(20200509L, 20200601L, 20200505L, 20200610L, 20200612L, 20200529L)

strptime(dates, "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "2020-05-09 CEST" "2020-06-01 CEST" "2020-05-05 CEST"
# [4] "2020-06-10 CEST" "2020-06-12 CEST" "2020-05-29 CEST"
```

or in combination with `as.Date`

```
as.Date(strptime(dates, "%Y%m%d"))
# [1] "2020-05-09" "2020-06-01" "2020-05-05" "2020-06-10" "2020-06-12"
# [6] "2020-05-29"
```

**PS** The documentation (c.f. `?strptime`) provides a lot of interesting information for date parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package has a bunch of functions that make dealing with dates simple and easy.  It looks like `ymd` should work for you (year/month/day).

```
library(lubridate)

# character
fecha <- '20200509'
# or numeric
fecha <- 20200509

fecha_nueva <- ymd(fecha)

[1] "2020-05-09"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at that page:

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-format-a-string-containing-a-date-into-r-date-object/

There’s a good explanation of how to read custom date format.

Case 1 is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(df1$fechas)
#[1] "2020-05-09" "2020-06-01" "2020-05-05" "2020-06-10" "2020-06-12" "2020-05-29"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(fechas = c(20200509L, 20200601L, 20200505L, 20200610L, 
20200612L, 20200529L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```